# Airbnb Superset iframe needs login

Tags: html, iframe, apache-superset

I am sharing a slice from Airbnb Superset data visualization tool as an iframe to a webpage.

Its asking for login, how can i bypass the login ?

Is there some setting/config that I can set in Admin settings ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes You can Bypass the login by editing public role. Just give necessary permission to public role and that will solve our problem.

For more Information go through this discussion

[Super set without using login](https://github.com/airbnb/superset/issues/264)

Comment: any specific permission that you know of, there are close to more than 100 permissions, and i am not able which one should do.